# Way to reduce treespacing after stabilize() has been executed?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm working on a small simulation program and I use vis.js to create hierarchical trees. When I do this they are spread out pretty far. Using myNetwork.stabilize() fixes this but the spacing between the trees stays the same and adjusting treeSpacing after I use stabilize() won't work. I've added to sreenshots to illustrate what I mean since it's hard for me to describe it.

[Picture without myNetwork.stabilize()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH0NY.jpg)

[Picture with myNetwork.stabilize()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0IBR.jpg)

I'd like to have the stabilized trees with shorter gaps between individual trees.

Edit:

Solved it with the help of Jason B. After I initiated the tree I used the following code to get what I wanted.

```
result_Tree.setOptions({physics:{
    solver: "barnesHut"
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your options:

```
var options = {
  configure: {
    enabled: true,
    filter: 'nodes,edges',
    container: yourcontainersname,
    showButton: true
  }
}
```

This will show you the configuration interface which will allow you to play around with different visual options on your network and then generate the code by the push of a button once you have it looking visually how you want it.

This should allow you to figure out which option will help bring your trees closer together.

Comment: I'll try that. I forgot to mention that treespacing is something which only applies when physics are disabled for the network and stabilize() enables the physics. I havn't found a way to alter the options after I initialized them. Otherwise I would just disable physics after stablize() is done and then reduce the tree spacing.

Comment: This actually helped me - thanks! You might want to change your answer a bit. The option filter should just be true to have access to all available options (I needed to change it to that to find a solution (solver=barnesHut)) and container should be "yourcontainer" instead of undefined. Thanks again for nudging me in the right direction ;)

Comment: Glad I was able to help! @Shiroco